# Accessing data from model class from a separate class

Tags: swift

Im still trying to learn Swift so bear with me..

Essentially I have a model class that gets data from a URLSession from a website. I want to parse the json and store variables in this class, and then access the variables from my viewController.

I'm having trouble doing this, basically if I print out the array at the end of the parsing function in the model class, they get printed correctly. However, if I create a variable in the viewController class that calls the models function, the array that gets returned is empty.

I can paste my code when I get a chance, but I was just curious if anyone knew a good tutorial/practice for doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the `HTTP Request` from the `Model`. The `HTTP Request` should be done separately, the implementation technique is upto you since it's debated which is the best way to approach it, but ultimately once you get the `JSON` from this `HTTP object`, you should then instantiate the `model object` with the `json` in order to set the `class variables`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jay said, you should use a network Request to get the data separately, then you need to use `protocol` to pass data to your `ViewController`.

I use `SwiftyJSON` to cast the json object, but you can create your own as well.